# Keycloak 4.3.0 Infinite Loop Scenario

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I have included the keycloak.js in the head of my index page. Upon a successful login I am redirected back to my defined redirect url where authenticated is equal to true. However, after about 5 seconds the page reloads and return authenticated true. This just happens in a loop and not sure where to go from here. Here is what I have in my html:

```
<script src="/js/application/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/application/keycloak.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var keycloak = Keycloak('keycloak.json');    
    keycloak.init({onLoad:'login-required', flow:'standard'}).success(function(authenticated) {         
        console.log('load app here');
    }).error(function() {
        alert('failed to initialize');
    });
});
```

My keycloak.json is:

```
{
"realm": "myapp",
"auth-server-url": "https://localhost:8081/auth",
"ssl-required": "external",
"resource": "app",
"credentials": {
  "secret": "77296286-f52d-48d9-82ac-fcf287486110"
 },
 "confidential-port": 0,
 "policy-enforcer": {},
 }
```

I really appreciate any suggestions you have. This is mainly happening in IE 11. We have a lot of mom and pop customers that still use IE 11 so gotta support it.

I am using the keycloak.js from 4.3.0 and using all of the java 4.3.0 adpaters.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, checkLoginIframe:false didn't fix the issue for me. After reading the documentation for keycloak iframe and the discussion here I revisited the idea that the browser is the issue.

I turned off third-party cookie blocking for Chrome & Safari & Shields off for Brave. The refresh issue has disappeared for me. MS Edge is unaffected by this.

The following documentation provided a clue: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/securing_apps/topics/oidc/javascript-adapter.adoc#modern-browsers-with-tracking-protection

Comment: Discussion is a bit old, but I had the same issue today with a checkLoginIframe enabled on brave. I ended in an infinite loop until I disabled brave shield.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this issue. The issue was not with chrome. The issue was because of an iframe. KeyCloak append iframe in your browser window and iframe then sends a request to KeyCloak server for authentication before a response comes back and iframe update parent window about response KeyCloak library was appending one more iframe, which results in an infinite loop. So I just added a condition in KeyCloak library, if the iframe is already in the window do not append new iframe.

add "checkLoginIframe": true in the init method of keycloak service it will solve your issue.

Refer below github link :

https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-reactjs-demo/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix this w/o changing code is to init it like this.

`keycloak.init({onLoad: 'login-required',"checkLoginIframe" : false})`

where checkloginiframe is disabled

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with react and Keycloak 19.0.0. It is solved by removing <React.StrictMode>